# Not showing Dynamic table cell height in Grouped Table View iphone

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uitableview, height

I have Grouped Table View in which I want to display Contact details. But details are of dynamic length so I need dynamic height for cell. It works for some section but not working for remianing section. Here is my code

```
    #define PHONE_DETAIL_SECTION 0
    #define EMAIL_DETAIL_SECION 1
        #define URL_DETAIL_SECTION 2
        #define ADDRESS_DETAIL_SECTION 3
        #define BIRTHDAY_DETAIL_SECTION 4
        #define NOTE_DETAIL_SECTION 5
        #define CONSTRAINT_WIDTH 320.0f
        #define FONT_SIZE 17.0f
        #define MARGIN_SIZE 20.0f
        #define NO_OF_SECTION 6


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return NO_OF_SECTION;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {

        case PHONE_DETAIL_SECTION:
            return [APP_DELGATE.phonenumberDetailLabelArray count];

        case EMAIL_DETAIL_SECION:
            return [APP_DELGATE.emailLabelDetailArray count];

        case URL_DETAIL_SECTION:
            return [APP_DELGATE.urlLabelDetailArray count];

        case ADDRESS_DETAIL_SECTION:
                return [APP_DELGATE.addressDetailLabelArray count]; 

        case BIRTHDAY_DETAIL_SECTION:
            if(birthdateString)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;

        case NOTE_DETAIL_SECTION:
                if(noteString)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"section:::%d",indexPath.section);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // DetailCell is subclass of UITableCell which 
    // contains only 2 labels:- lblName & lblValue

    DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *cellArray=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
    }

    if (indexPath.section==PHONE_DETAIL_SECTION) {

        cell.lblName.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.phonenumberDetailLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.phonenumberDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        NSLog(@" 222222 suggested size height ph no => %f",suggestedSize.height);
        cell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblValue.frame.origin.x, cell.lblValue.frame.origin.y, cell.lblValue.frame.size.width, suggestedSize.height);

        cell.lblValue.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.phonenumberDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else if(indexPath.section==EMAIL_DETAIL_SECION) {

        cell.lblName.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.emailLabelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0;

        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.emailDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        cell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblValue.frame.origin.x, cell.lblValue.frame.origin.y, cell.lblValue.frame.size.width, suggestedSize.height);

        cell.lblValue.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.emailDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    else if(indexPath.section==URL_DETAIL_SECTION) {

        cell.lblName.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.urlLabelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.urlDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        NSLog(@" 222222 suggested size height url => %f",suggestedSize.height);
        cell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblValue.frame.origin.x, cell.lblValue.frame.origin.y, cell.lblValue.frame.size.width, suggestedSize.height);

        cell.lblValue.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.urlDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    else if (indexPath.section==ADDRESS_DETAIL_SECTION) {

        cell.lblName.text=(NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.addressDetailLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.addressDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

         cell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblValue.frame.origin.x, cell.lblValue.frame.origin.y, cell.lblValue.frame.size.width, suggestedSize.height);

         cell.lblValue.text = (NSString*)[APP_DELGATE.addressDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    }

    else if(indexPath.section==BIRTHDAY_DETAIL_SECTION) {

        NSString *birthdateStringLocal=[ContactDetails getBirthDate:record];
        cell.lblName.text=BIRTHDAY_LABEL;

        cell.lblValue.text=birthdateStringLocal;
    }

    else if(indexPath.section==NOTE_DETAIL_SECTION) {

        cell.lblName.text=NOTES_LABEL;
        cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGSize suggestedSize = [noteString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        cell.lblValue.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblValue.frame.origin.x, cell.lblValue.frame.origin.y, cell.lblValue.frame.size.width, suggestedSize.height);

        cell.lblValue.text=noteString;

    }

    return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section==PHONE_DETAIL_SECTION){

        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.phonenumberDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"1111111suggested size height Phone no=> %f",suggestedSize.height);
        return suggestedSize.height + MARGIN_SIZE;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section==ADDRESS_DETAIL_SECTION){

        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.addressDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"1111111suggested size height Address=> %f",suggestedSize.height);
        return suggestedSize.height + MARGIN_SIZE;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section==EMAIL_DETAIL_SECION){

        NSLog(@"String 1111: %@", [APP_DELGATE.emailDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.emailDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"1111111suggested size height Email=> %f",suggestedSize.height);
        return suggestedSize.height + MARGIN_SIZE;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == NOTE_DETAIL_SECTION){
        CGSize suggestedSize = [noteString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"1111111suggested size height NOTES=> %f",suggestedSize.height);
        return suggestedSize.height + MARGIN_SIZE;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == URL_DETAIL_SECTION){
        CGSize suggestedSize = [[APP_DELGATE.urlDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CONSTRAINT_WIDTH, LONG_LONG_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"1111111suggested size height URL=> %f",suggestedSize.height);
        return suggestedSize.height + MARGIN_SIZE;
    }
    else 
        return 50;
}
```

I am dynamic table cell height for Address & Notes but not for Email , Phone no, URL. If the phone no or url is long enough then it doesn't show anything.
Please see following screenshots

[image]

[image]

Any knid of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it happens because you give CONSTRAINT_WIDTH=320.0f i think it is approx 200.0F so make this change and then see the result i think your problem is resolved. 
and more think use this for your value labels `cell.lblValue.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works perfectly just by changing CONSTRAINT_WIDTH.

Comment: Can you tell me why do I need to set cell.lblValue.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap; ? Because I have already set cell.lblValue.numberOfLines = 0.

Comment: because default `UILineBreakMode` is set to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` so if you want to link break by words then you have to use this.